# SQL group by on a repetitive value in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a SQL table looking like this in MySQL:

```
id  technician_id  actionDate  station_id
1     10           1317909863      1
2     10           1317909864      1
3     10           1317909865      1
4     10           1317909866      2
5     10           1317909867      2
6     10           1317909868      2
7     10           1317909869      2
8     10           1317909870      2
9     10           1317909871      3
10    10           1317909872      1
11    10           1317909873      1
```

This data is to track technician on the field. The id column an auto-increment key. The actionDate column is number of seconds since 1970, and the station_id is the id of the station on the field on which the technician is doing the action.

I would like to determine some "statistics" from this data. For example, I would like to determine the route the technician did ( went from station 1 to 2, then from 2 to 3, then from 3 came back to 1). Also would like to determine how much time he spent everytime he went to a station (ex: he went to station 1, stayed 3 minutes, then took his car for 30 minutes to go to station 2, stayed 15 minutes, then took his car to go to station 3 in 20 minutes, stayed 10 minutes then came back to 1).

As you can get it, this is a tracking system. I need to order by the actionDate, then group by the station_id. But since some stations can be visited more than 1 time by the technician, it cannot be grouped by that column.

Any pointers?

I had this, but it regroups ALL the rows having the same station_id:

```
select station_id, min(actionDate), max(actionDate) 
from Action
where technician_id = 10
group by station_id
order by actionDate;
```

Comment: Would be so easy if MySQL finally arrived in the 21st century and implemented windowing functions.

Comment: Can you not do CTEs in MySQL?

Comment: @JNK I'm pretty sure you can't, it's subqueries and temp tables instead!

Comment: @JNK: no MySQL doesn't support any of the modern SQL features like CTE or windowing functions.

Answer (score 1):

I hate recommending cursors, but looking at that, it seems to be a candidate for one.  A cursor could zip once through that data, populating a temporary table as it goes.

I have spent a lot of time with similar problems looking for overlapping time ranges etc, and have come to realise that there are situations when running a cursor is a better and faster option.

Maybe someone here can suggest otherwise...

Let me know if you need an example.

Comment: +1 - there's really no easy set-based solution to this that you could implement in a simple query.

Comment: @EricPetroelje: there is, just not with MySQL

Answer (score 0):

This would easier in mssql but this article might help, http://www.explodybits.com/2011/11/mysql-row-number/

For the first part you want query where the row number is 1 partitioning by the station id.